# Set automatic proxy and configuration URL in Ubuntu 22.04 terminal

Tags: networking, 22.04, configuration, proxy

I have set automatic proxy and configuration URL in Ubuntu 22.04 GUI. How could I find the configuration files and introduce this information in the Terminal?

I have internet connection and access to the browsers but I cannot update or install packages as the terminal cannot connect to the internet.

sudo apt-get update gives several errors.

Err:1 it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease Connection failed [IP: ]. Failed to fetch it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease Connection failed [IP: ].

I have tried Internet connection with ping (ping -c 3 google.com):
PING google.com (142.250.184.110) 6(84) bytes of data. --- google.com ping statistics --- 3 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 2036ms.

These errors make me think Ubuntu command line is not connecting to Internet.

Comment: More details needed. What commands have you used? What errors do you get? What do you mean the terminal can not connect?

Comment: Please edit the question and add this info, Not in the comments. Comments are where you get asked.